# trying to plot 3 different arrays corresponding to x,y,z

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to make a plot figure of happiness degree in 30 different countries from the year 2012 to 2018, some years are missing happiness degree value.
the arrays are Happiness, Year and Country.

I want the y axis to be the happiness degree, the x axis to be the Years and the Y to be the country(each country is marked by a number from 1-30), so that there will be a color connecting all the different degrees through the years from each country.

The shape of each array is (210,). Here is my code:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as tri

sns.set(style="white")

x=Year
y=Hapiness
z=country

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50, 50))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

nptsx, nptsy = 100, 100
xg, yg = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), nptsx),
                 np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), nptsy))

triangles = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
tri_interp = tri.CubicTriInterpolator(triangles, z)
zg = tri_interp(xg, yg)

# change levels here according to your data
levels = np.linspace(1, 210, 30)
colormap = ax.contourf(xg, yg, zg, levels,
                   cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                   norm=plt.Normalize(vmax=z.max(), vmin=z.min()))
# plot data points
ax.plot(x, y, color="#444444", marker="o", linestyle="", markersize=15)

# add a colorbar
fig.colorbar(colormap,
         orientation='vertical',  # horizontal colour bar
         shrink=0.85)

# graph extras: look at xlim and ylim
ax.set_xlim((2012, 2018))
ax.set_ylim((0, 10))
ax.set_aspect("equal", "box")

plt.show()
```

Here is the error I get when I run the code:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call 
last)
<ipython-input-65-2779759126bf> in <module>
     16                      np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), nptsy))
     17 
---> 18 triangles = tri.Triangulation(x, y)
     19 tri_interp = tri.CubicTriInterpolator(triangles, z)
     20 zg = tri_interp(xg, yg)

 C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\tri\triangulation.py in __init__(self, x, y, 
    triangles, mask)
     52             # No triangulation specified, so use 
matplotlib._qhull to obtain
     53             # Delaunay triangulation.
---> 54             self.triangles, self._neighbors =_qhull.delaunay(x,y)
     55             self.is_delaunay = True
     56         else:

RuntimeError: Error in qhull Delaunay triangulation calculation: input inconsistency (exitcode=1); use python verbose option (-v) to see original qhull error.
```

A sample of my data (.CSV file):

```
Entity     Code Year    World Happiness Report(Cantril Ladder(0=worst; 10=best))
Argentina   1   2012    6.4
Argentina   1   2013    6.5
Argentina   1   2014    6.6
Argentina   1   2015    6.6
Argentina   1   2016    6.4
Argentina   1   2017    6.0
Argentina   1   2018    5.7
Australia   2   2012    7.1
Australia   2   2013    7.3
Australia   2   2014    7.2
Australia   2   2015    7.3
Australia   2   2016    7.2
Australia   2   2017    7.2
Australia   2   2018    7.1
Brazil      3   2012    6.6
Brazil      3   2013    7.1
Brazil      3   2014    6.9
Brazil      3   2015    6.5
Brazil      3   2016    6.3
Brazil      3   2017    6.3
Brazil      3   2018    6.1
```

Comment: could you please provide some example data for x,y,z so that it would be possible to reproduce your code

Comment: I will include it my question above

Comment: Can you try running python with `-v` as suggested by the error message, to see if you get a more informative error about what made qhull crash?

Comment: I don't have the error when running your code. Do you still have it with this sample ? If not, try to find which part of your data is causing the bug, and post this part instead.

Comment: Yeah it did run when I removed some of data with missing values, I'm now a bit confused though, not sure if it actually does what I have in mind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your error is in the way you read your csv file, without assigning a type to your data it will be treated as a String.

try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("untitled.csv", delimiter=',')

x=np.array(df['Year'].values, dtype='float')
y=np.array(df['Happiness'].values, dtype='float')
z=np.array(df['Code'].values, dtype='int')
```

Comment: if so close the question :)